# iOS/Objective-C: Swipe to Left causing crash in tableview created with code

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, delete-row

I have a tableview that is crashing when you swipe left to delete.  It crashes after the deletion when the tableview reloads at a point in cellfor row atindexpath that references the indexpath. The other wrinkle is that table does not reload until receipt of notice of a successful deletion on the server.  Nevertheless, I can't figure out what is causing the crash.  Is there another delegate needed. Do I have to manually change the indexpath?  Thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

Here is my code:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (tableView == _myTableView ) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
           Items *itemToDelete = [_myItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];     
            NSNumber *iidToDelete = itemToDelete.iid;     
     //CREATE DICTIONARY AND SEND TO SERVER FOR DELETION           
                    [self postToServerDelete:data andItem:itemToDelete];
        }
        }
    }
    -(void) postToServerDelete: (NSData *) data andItem:(Items *)itemToDelete  {
          //SEND TO SERVER
                        if (successint==1) {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{              
                                [_managedObjectContext deleteObject:itemToDelete];
                                NSError* error;
                       [self getItems];//refreshes items list from managedobjectcontext
                            if ([_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {   
                                [_myTableView reloadData];
                            }        
                        });
}
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
        static NSString *StepRowIdentifier = @"RowIdentifier";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RowIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:RowIdentifier] ;   
        }
        //LINE WHERE CRASH OCCURS
        Items* item = [[self getItems] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *steptext= item.name;
        cell.textLabel.text=name;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What does the crash say? Your stack trace?

Comment: You've got a handful of things going wrong here. You don't show where `_managedObjectContext` comes from. Is it `[self getItems]`? in `postToServerDelete`, you have `andItem:(Steps*)stepToDelete`... Seems you copy / pasted some code and didn't change the 'template' to suit what you're doing.  And does `deleteObject` remove it from the array I imagine `[self getItems]` returns? If not, you need to, or you're going to reach a dangling pointer when reloading your table.

Comment: the crash is lldb.  can post bt if you think it would be helpful...too long to fit in a comment

Comment: the managedObjectContext is from core data and that line successfully deletes the object.  [self getItems returns an array of these custom objects fetched from Core Data and I have also added a line to make sure it gets refreshed--see above.  I also tried manually deleting the object from the array for what it's worth but no difference.)  The problem seems to be that even after the deletion, when the table loads, it tries to load the old number of items, not the number (one less) after the deletion and on the final cycle, it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This crash line

```
 Items* item = [[self getItems] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Basically could be caused by 2 things:

> 1. self getItems is returning other than array (or null).
> 2. if it does return an array, then the index at which you specified no longer exist.

I suspect it is case 2, since you mention about deletion. And I see code, you seem to delete _myItems, but you refer to [self getItems] in cellForRow. These two need to be the same object.

Comment: The problem does seem to be 2.  The array is not nil.  After the deletion, cellForRow is still called the same number of times.  So if there were 4 items, and you delete one, it is still called four times.  On the fourth time, there is no longer an object in the Array at that index.  Is there something other method I need to include so that cellforrow knows that a deletion has taken place?

Comment: If you use same object for cellForRow and commitEditing delegate, then there should be no problem. Try replacing: Items* item = [[self getItems] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; with Items* item = [_myItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];